# How to insert rows in another table based on insert in first table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If any insert happens in table A then,i need to insert the last inserted row into table B.

How can I do it by using @@rowcount.

I am trying below code.

```
create table table1
(
id int identity(1,1),
column1 nvarchar
)

create table table2
(
id int identity(1,1),
column1 nvarchar
)


Create  procedure insert1
    @column1 nvarchar    
AS    
Declare @t int,@column2 nvarchar    
insert into table1 values(@column1)    
select * from table1    
set @t= (Select @@IDENTITY from table1)      
Insert into table2 values (@t)
```

Please let me know how can i do the same by trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgTableAInsert
ON dbo.Table1
FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(Column1)
       SELECT Column1
       FROM Inserted
```

Points to note:

- a trigger is called **once per statement**, e.g. if your `INSERT` statement inserts 10 rows, the trigger is called **once** and `Inserted` contains those 10 newly inserted rows (do you want to insert all 10 of those into `TableB`?)
- I would recommend to always use the schema prefix on tables (the `dbo.` part)
- I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of columns, both on an `INSERT` as well as a `SELECT` statement - don't omit those! (or you might run into messy and hard-to-debug issues when suddenly one of the tables changes)

Answer (score 1):

MERGE INTO Table1 AS t1
USING MyTable ON 1=0 -- always generates "not matched by target"

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    -- INSERT into Table1:
    INSERT (A, B, C) VALUES (t1.A, t1.B, t1.C)

--- .. and INSERT into Table2:
OUTPUT inserted.ID, MyTable.D, MyTable.E, MyTable.F
INTO Table2 (ID, D, E, F);